# Calling a servlet without url-pattern dependency

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

### I have resolved the issue now. Thank you very much

Ok. Let me explain my issue in detail.

Here's my web.xml

```
<servlet>
<display-name>PDFOpen</display-name>
<servlet-name>PDFOpen</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.cc.wdk.custom.admin.db.OpenPdfServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>PDFOpen</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/component/main/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have a button in my jsp and on the click of the button I want my servlet to be called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPDF(){

//Call my servlet here

}
</script>
```

JSP component:

```
<dmf:button name="Submit"onclick="openPDF" id="openPDFId" runatclient="true">
</dmf:button>
```

The javascript is getting called on the click of the button. The main issue that I am facing is the servlet is getting triggerred as soon as the main page loads. (the URL for the home page has /component/main/ in it) which is the url-pattern I have given in web.xml ). But I don't want it this way. It has to get triggrered when the button is clicked. And even after button is clicked the URL will be the same since it stays on the same page. How do I achieve this. I hope I have made sense in my explaination.

Comment: Please post the code you are having trouble with

Comment: This sounds like you need AJAX.  Click your button, ajax a call to your servlet, do something with the results.